# How to run JavaScript and click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the next task - I have a page where we have some interaction logic:
After a user clicks a button, my script redirects the user to another site where it must be populate 2 textfields then click button, after redirect to new page it must click on another button.

My project is based on ASP.NET MVC4.

My questions are:

1. May I do all of this?
2. If yes, how can I redirect to another page and run my script

P.S.: Second web site isn't my site and everything I know is id of buttons where I need to click.

Comment: You could do this on the server or with a user script or HTA but no other browser based way

Comment: what do you mean? May you answer more closely?

Comment: Is the second site on the same domain? Based on your explanation I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want.

Comment: No, second site is under another domain. Second website is third party website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment

You cannot do this in a normal browser. You could write a bookmarklet or two that would navigate and click but there is no script you can write in a web page that will do what you want for security reasons. A long time ago, it was possible in IE to load a banking site into an iFrame and script and monitor user interaction to steal credentials. This has been blocked.

If you save an HTML page with the extension HTA, it can be loaded from harddisk in windows and will have relaxed security so you could load the other site into an iFrame and script the interaction. This is likely not what you want.

The last method is to use for example CURL to get the foreign page, insert stuff and submit the form to the foreign site and return the result. This is not recommended either.

So the question to you is: Why do you need this and are there other ways to do what you want

Comment: I need this for next reason: I have a website where testing challengers before invite there by interview. Our challenger come to our resource from job marketplace, where they apply job vacation, then arrive mail with link to our project, where they get test. If test is unsuccessfull I need to redirect automatically my program to job marketplace and take away challengers accept. And for this purposes I need my script. My site and job marketplace is different projects. Also I can't have an access to server side logic of Job marketplace. Do you have any ideas? P.S.: I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Only reliable way is on the server. Perhaps with access to an API of the marketplace (like linkedIn has)

Answer (score 0):

1) location.href = "http://another.page.com"
2) impossible for security purposes